# Do quick connects with water stops impact the performance of a sprinkler/irrigation system?

Tags: irrigation

I have just installed a less than usual irrigation system, the design was chosen in order to minimize the digging and still have coverage of the backyard. The area I am irrigating is a L shape with a factor size that allows me to cover the entire area with three oscillating sprinklers from GardenaThe piping is done in such a way that it would allow me to install a quick connect at the end of each line and I will use a short hose with quick connect heads at both ends to connect either the above oscillating sprinklers or if I want to , I can connect a longer hose and with a nozzle and do spot watering if I really want or get water to any point of the property from there (much more convenient than running a 50' hose every time from the tap to those remote corners.

Here is a picture of the head of the pipe. As you can see right now I am using a fixed connector there but the plan is to replace it with quick connects so I can remove them when I mow the grass. These will sit recessed under the ground level but still accessible. The plan is to have them with water stop. The oscillating sprinkler end has a quick connect with water stop already.

My question is: is having two water stops there going to affect the performance of the sprinklers ?At this moment I have enough pressure (it is one sprinkler per line, one line active at a time) at the sprinkler and so I need to limit the oscillation limits in order to stop the water reaching the fences

Also a related question: I can't seem to find brass quick connectors with water stop on Amazon.ca. I used these very key words (brass quick connector and water stop) but nothing came up as result (I do get the plastic gardena ones but I want these to be brass)

[image]

**Update: What is a water stop**
Some of the readers seem to be unfamiliar with this feature
Finding quick connects is not a problem. Finding brass quick connectors with water stop seems to be a problem. Not sure if this is because technically is more difficult to make them of brass.

The water stop helps when you want to swap let's say an oscillating sprinkler in my case with a nozzle. You do not need to shut off the water valve in order not to get sprayed with water when you switch them. As seen in this movie you just simply remove one and replace it with the other one
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBkvc9v77Lo&ab_channel=HydroSure

Comment: For those unfamiliar with them: I believe "water stop" here refers to the fact that some quick connects have a built in valve which automatically stops flow when they are disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

Most quick connects with stops have a relatively small open area.  You might want to install a ball valve shutoff and a quick connect without a stop.  Make sure that both parts have large open areas, usually found in brass components.

Comment: Exactly what I would have suggested.

Comment: The reason why I would like to have a quick connect with water stop at the ground end as well (the nozzle/sprinkler end already has it) is two folds: 1) I can switch/swap the hose  with a longer one without shotting off the valve 2) the stop prevents dirt and grass clippings to get inside the pipe and clog the sprinkler filter later

Comment: @MiniMe 1) You would still have a quick connect, it just wouldn't include a stop. Swapping hoses is just a quarter turn to shut off the ball valve, do the QC thing, and flip the valve back on. 2) You can purge the QC before connecting a hose by just turning the ball valve on part way for a moment. That will flush out any spiders, pencil cacti, ... that have taken up residence in the outlet. [Dramm](https://www.dramm.com/html/main.isx?sub=474) #300 valves have been my choice. QCs have been a mixed lot.

Comment: That could work but adding that Dramm fitting and the quick connect on top of it will raise the whe tjing above the soil level and for mowing purposes I want it to stay under that level